# Phoenix - OTP release causing conn.secret_key_base not set error

Tags: phoenix-framework

This is surely a gap in my understanding so I am hoping someone could help clarify.

Over [here](http://www.phoenixframework.org/v1.2.0/docs/advanced-deployment) in the phoenix docs, it says:

```
# If you are doing OTP releases, you need to instruct Phoenix
# to start the server for all endpoints:
#
    config :phoenix, :serve_endpoints, true
```

I am not quite sure, what effect this has on a simple app, but actually not setting this also seems to work. In fact, enabling this is causing the below error:

"phoenix cookie store expects conn.secret_key_base to be set"

What is this setting for and why is it needed? If it is not enabled, everything seems to work ok.

Answer (score 0):

Phoenix docs are outdated.

As I can see you'v forgot your `prod.secret.exs` while compiling.

In case you are building that for test purpose and it's not recommended to be in production but could be set like that:

```
# Configures the endpoint
config :hello_phoenix, HelloPhoenix.Endpoint,
  secret_key_base: "SECRET_KEY"
```